# Flutter Lasso selection for markers

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to select muliple markers at onetime and to select markers by drawing a lasso and the markers beside area of the lasso be selected but actully I don't know how to do that and I didn't find any package or tutorial doing that so I wonder if someone can help me even if with just telling me the logic not a full code.

[Example for what I want to do](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QzOz6.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flutter has a [ClipPath()](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ClipPath-class.html) widget that can clip a child with a structured path (like Photoshop path+layer->create vector mask, or drawing a path with the lasso tool and cutting out the image). You can have a Container() contain a background image, and clip it with ClipPath().

```
ClipPath(
  clipper: MyClipperPath(), //you can pass in your own args if you want
  child: Container(
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
      image: DecorationImage(
        image: //your image - AssetImage(), NetworkImage() etc.
        fit: BoxFit.fill, //or whatever BoxFit you want
      )
    )
  )
)
```

Then outside your widget class

```
class MyClipperPath extends CustomClipper<Path> {
  MyClipperPath();

  @override
  Path getClip(Size size) {
    //size.height and size.width are the width and height of your child: Container() above

    Path path = Path();
    path.moveTo(0,0);
    path.lineTo(size.width,0);
    path.lineTo(size.width/3,size.height/3);
    path.lineTo(0,size.height);
    path.close();
    
    return path;
  }
}
```

The above path is an L-like shape. Change the lineTo values and you'll see the clipping path update on screen.

The [Path class](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/Path-class.html) has a bunch of methods to create lines and curves, including multiple methods for bezier segment types which is what you'd use to copy the way paths or the lasso tool in Photoshop define arbitrary shapes.

Here's a CustomClipper object I'm using in my app. It creates an S-shaped edge on a box.

```
class TabClipper extends CustomClipper<Path> {
  final double radius;
  const TabClipper([this.radius = 0]);
  @override
  Path getClip(Size size) {
    double _radius = radius;
    if(_radius==0) _radius = size.height * 16 / 57;
    final path = Path();
    path.arcToPoint(Offset(_radius,_radius), radius: Radius.circular(_radius*0.95),rotation: 90.0);
    path.lineTo(_radius, size.height - _radius);
    path.arcToPoint(Offset(_radius*2,size.height), radius: Radius.circular(_radius*0.95),rotation: 90.0, clockwise: false);
    path.lineTo(size.width, size.height);
    path.lineTo(size.width, 0.0);
    path.close();
    return path;
  }

  @override
  bool shouldReclip(CustomClipper oldClipper) {return false;}
}
```